# Android app crashes without error, try-catch fails to fire

Tags: android

I'm trying to get a user's location using Android's FusedLocationProviderClient.

This line of code causes my app to crash with no error: `fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getActivity());`

I tried surrounding it in a try-catch to print an exception, but the catch branch never executes and my app still crashes without error.

Does anyone know what could be causing this? Not that it should matter, but I'm actually making an Android plugin for a Godot program.

I just think it's beyond strange that my app could be crashing at that line without giving me an error message in ADB *or* executing the catch branch.

Comment: Does your app stop crashing if you comment out that line? Also, what type are you catching in your `catch` clause?

Comment: May be your test device doesn't have Google Play service so you cannot use google service API

Comment: @Egor Yes. I am catching an Exception.

Comment: @TamHuynh I've tried it with devices that have Google Play and Google APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the necessary permissions declared in your AndroidManifest.xml and that you request runtime permission , or handle provide it

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```